# How to create simple class in android sdk?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I create simple android project in Eclipse with help of Android SDK my code is:

```
package com.example.deomanapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Helpers;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                Mhelper mhelper = new Mhelper();


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                mhelper.mContext();
                TextView tx = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                tx.setText("Hi");

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ssss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
         });
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

I wanted to write more code in other class so i create helper class in the project :
    package com.example.deomanapp;

```
import com.example.deomanapp.MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Mhelper {


    public void mContext(Context context)
    {
        LocationManager lm;
        lm   = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

    }
}
```

My problem is i can not pass **Context** to any part of **class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment** or in the **mhelper.mContext();** (it need Contex parameter) .

How can i take button onClick out of there to other class? or How can i make this code works? Should my new class extends from other class ?

Edit:

log :

```
04-20 02:14:51.210: D/gralloc_goldfish(1223): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-20 02:14:54.530: I/Choreographer(1223): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-20 02:16:06.950: D/gralloc_goldfish(1275): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-20 02:16:11.050: D/AndroidRuntime(1275): Shutting down VM
04-20 02:16:11.050: W/dalvikvm(1275): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3afcba8)
04-20 02:16:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 02:16:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1275): Process: com.example.deomanapp, PID: 1275
04-20 02:16:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1275): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-20 02:16:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1275):     at com.example.deomanapp.Mhelper.mContext(Mhelper.java:22)
04-20 02:16:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1275):     at com.example.deomanapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:87)
04-20 02:16:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1275):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
04-20 02:16:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1275):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
04-20 02:16:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1275):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-20 02:16:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1275):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-20 02:16:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1275):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-20 02:16:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1275):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-20 02:16:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1275):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 02:16:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1275):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-20 02:16:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1275):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-20 02:16:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1275):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-20 02:16:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1275):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 02:16:16.370: I/Process(1275): Sending signal. PID: 1275 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please follow Java conventions and start class names with a capital letter. Small letters are for variable and method names.

Comment: I changed it to capital , but same errors.

Comment: @Shombol-shagol the crash is no because of that. The suggestion was to follow some convention while naming class. That is has nothing to do with the crash

Comment: @Shombol-shagol what is line 22 in `Mhelper.java`

Comment: @Shombol-shagol did you make this  change  `lm   = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);` ??. You still have  `lm   = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);`

Comment: @Raghunandan yes i changed it.second one give me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
 mhelper.mContext(getActivity());
```

And then

```
  lm   = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29)

```
public final Activity getActivity ()

Added in API level 11
Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.
```

Comment: It give me no error but the program crash on button click with nullpointexeption.

Comment: @Shombol-shagol post the stacktrace. It will indicate the cause

Comment: 04-20 01:18:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1130): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Shombol-shagol need the full stacktrace. my guess `getLastKnownLocation` returns null. Its upto you to correct that

Comment: @Shombol-shagol what is line 22 in `Mhelper.java`?

Comment: I change the name of class helper to Mhelper to make it capital.

Comment: @Shombol-shagol what has that gotta do with the crash??. How long have you been programming??

Comment: @Shombol-shagol do you know which line is line 22 in `Mhelper.java`??

Comment: it is :double longitude = location.getLongitude();

Comment: @Shombol-shagol that means location is null. Why? `lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);` returns null. As i said `getLastKnownLocation` can return null

Comment: It seems you are right, it crash because this function return null,I should change it.